# Highcharts column width with variable x axis point spacing

Tags: highcharts

So I have an x axis of type `datetime`, and a series of type `column`:

http://jsfiddle.net/drmrbrewer/215tnLna/3/

Now, in reality, the spacing of points on the x axis may not always be uniform as in the above example.  For example, let's drop a couple of the points to create a non-uniform spacing:

http://jsfiddle.net/drmrbrewer/215tnLna/4/

What I'd like to happen is for each column to fill the entire span from the relevant point to the previous point, so that the gaps would be entirely filled in the above example.

Is that possible?  Hopefully without some horrible hack?  From a quick search it seems that there is a suggestion that different series may be required (one for each column width).  I'm hoping that isn't the case because (a) it's complicated; and (b) I don't know in advance what spacings I'm going to encounter in the data, so it's even more complicated!

Thanks!

Comment: I doubt you'll stumble upon a "out of the box" solution here. Additional columns or series is probably needed. This `area` chart with `step` achieves a similar feel with very minimal changes, but doesn't have the "hover over column" feel unfortunately: [JSFiddle step area](http://jsfiddle.net/215tnLna/5/)

Comment: Column width can be set per series. If you want to set point width per point you would have to write some custom wrapper that would extend default Highcharts functionality.

Comment: Thanks for the input @Ondkloss.  I'm trying to compare your area/step solution with a solution that relies on multiple series, and I've stumbled at the first step.  All I've done as the first tiny step is to split the data into two separate series, hoping that the chart would look the same as my first jsfiddle (then I could proceed to do something more fancy), but the padding doesn't do what I expect... any idea why?  jsfiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/drmrbrewer/215tnLna/8/

Comment: So `grouping` and `linkedTo` help a bit: http://jsfiddle.net/drmrbrewer/215tnLna/9/

Comment: And here's an example with different column widths in linked series: http://jsfiddle.net/drmrbrewer/215tnLna/11/

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to make is a histogram, not a bar chart (even bar/column widths). Perhaps you need to use the histogram chart type? https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/histogram-series

Comment: Welcome to SO. Though the link might answer the question, it is better to add consolidated details out here so that the answers stands out even if the link is broken.